# ¿Como utilizar modelos de la clase User, AbstractUser AbstractBaseUser en un mismo proyecto de Django 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto, que tiene por propósito manejar 3 modelos distintos de usuarios, estos son:

1. Usuarios Primarios, que prácticamente es el modelo User que tiene Django por defecto (si no estoy equivocado), y la idea es que sean los únicos que puedan iniciar sesión en la URL `admin/` con su su nombre de usuario y contraseña. Además son los únicos que pueden navegar por todas las vistas de sitio.
2. Usuarios Secundarios, pueden navegar por ciertas vistas del sitio, tienen su propio login donde ingresan su correo electrónico y una contraseña.
3. Usuarios Terciarios, solo pueden acceder a una vista particular y deben ingresar su DNI y una contraseña.

Bueno, creé un proyecto y una app `usuarios`:

```
py manage.py startapp usuarios
```

---

Archivo `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    ...
    #
    'usuarios.apps.UsuariosConfig',

...

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'usuarios.UsuarioSecundario'
```

Archivo `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from .managers import UsuarioSecundarioManager


class UsuarioSecundario(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = UsuarioBibliotecaManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = "{0}".format(self.email)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email
```

Archivo `managers.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager


class UsuarioSecundarioManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email),)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(email=email, password=password,)

        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_active = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

---

```
py manage.py makemigrations
py manage.py migrate
```

Bueno, hasta aquí llegue pero no estoy seguro de cómo debo continuar.
Por lo que encontré aquí y en internet en general, casi todos trabajan con un mismo modelo de usuario para todo el proyecto.

- ¿Cómo sugieren que debería crear el resto de los usuarios?
- ¿Qué modelo debería migrar primero o los migro a todos juntos?
- ¿Cómo hago para volver a utilizar el `AUTH_USER_MODEL` con el que viene Django por defecto?

Muchas Gracias

Comment: `py manage.py magrate` ¿seguro que ese es el comando? conozco poquito de Django y tengo la certeza que debe existir un manejador de roles de usuario, trabajas un solo modelo de usuarios y dependiendo de los roles, habilitas permisos para las vistas

Comment: gracias @fredyfx, edite el comando, era `py manage.py migrate`. Respecto a los roles, si indague un poco, pero en este caso, el proyecto requiere 3 tipos de usuarios en tablas distintas, y que utilizaran 3 formularios distintos, por lo que en el modelo deberia tener distinto tipos de username, que serian charField, imageField e IntegerField para UsuarioPrimario, UsuarioSecundario y UsuarioTerciario respectivamente